# How do I make a smooth objector animator animation?

Tags: java, android

When I click the image, I want there to be a smooth object animator animation. Right now it hops to the coordinates, then it animates. Any suggestions? Here's the code:

```
testImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImage);


        testImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

        if (depends) {

            anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(testImage, "translationY", 0.f, +90);
            anim.setDuration(1000);

            anim.start();

            depends = false;
        } else {

            depends = true;
            anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(testImage, "translationY", 0.f, -90);
            anim.setDuration(1000);

            anim.start();

        }

            }
        });
```

Comment: use a TranslateAnimation

Comment: TranslateAnimation won't work for me. It only animates the image, not the on click event.

Comment: When you animate back to original coordinates, use (90, 0) instead. Object animator works on absolute values, not relative to current ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give him a start value, pass only the target value. It will use getTranslationY() to get the start value.

```
anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(testImage, "translationY", depends ? +90 : -90);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
depends = !depends;
```

Comment: Or alternatively; testImage.animate().setDuration(1000).translationY(targetValue) comes often handy if API 12+ is not an issue.